# How to plot dictionary values of each key in C#

Tags: c#, plot, data-visualization

I want to plot a line graph a dictionary with multiple values of each key for series that have the same X value. I have checked other post, however they are mostly about python and the ones about c# have a dictionary structure different than mine. My dictionary looks like this:

```
[12/3/2020 10:34:47 AM (20, 21, 30, 50, 20)]
[12/3/2020 10:34:59 AM (22, 20, 20, 30, 12)]
[12/3/2020 10:35:10 AM (32, 39, 21, 23, 40)]
```

And my dictionary type:

```
Dictionary<DateTime, dynamic> data = new Dictionary<DateTime, dynamic>();
```

Value tuples are of type `double` where key types are `DateTime`.
Here is what I have tried so far;

```
  chart1.Series.Add("series1");
  chart1.Series["series1"].Color = Color.Green;
  chart1.Series["series1"].Points.AddXY(data.Keys,data.Values);
```

The code above works for `Keys` but `Values` gives error saying values are not iterable.

I also tried a different way as below;

```
   chart1.DataSource = data; //data is the dictionary
   chart1.Series["series1"].XValueMember = "Key";
   chart1.Series["series1"].YValueMembers = "Value";
```

Again `Values` can not be displayed.

I can not access each tuple value to plot, (I could have created an array for tuple part but I want to learn how to do it with `<dynamic>`) can someone help me please?

Comment: my suggest is_ don´t use `dynamic` if you don´t **have** to. If you know the actual types at compile-time, use them. C# is a statically typed language. Anyway ´m pretty sure, `chart1.Series["series1"].Points.AddXY(...)` will throw a `NullReferenceException`, because you did not set `Points` to anything.

Comment: @HimBromBeere actually it says ArgumentException since it can not understand the dynamic type, if there will be no other suggestions I probably will have to change "dynamic" as you suggested.

Comment: `dynamic` type behaves like any other object types. It's just when you need to tell the program :  "I gave up on that type. You will have to figure it out at runtime. And don't ask me question I want the `MissTypedPropertyItGatToBeSomeWhere` now!".

Comment: @DragandDrop I see, thank you